# How to delete selected user? PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, delete-row

I am using PDO and I want to remove specified user from my members list. I made "delete" button to show on every single user, and I want when I click on any random user, to delete him. This is my second day trying to make that.

I made something like this:

```
$id = $user->id;
$sql = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id";
$query = $handler->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":id" => $id));
```

But this is not a solution, this will delete everyone why join that page. I want to make when i click "delete" button, to remove the user where that button was. I hope you understand me, I'll show you the picture how I want it to be.

[image]

Comment: can you show the form or javascript function involved? Also, where does `$user->id` come from?

Comment: @RamRaider It's just a form. Only thing i got is the code above.

Comment: @RamRaider I've made it from this [link](http://pastebin.com/7u2vgNbW)

Comment: @Monk As a general rule of thumb when people ask you to show your form, you need to post the HTML markup that makes up the form, not a screenshot of how it looks.

Comment: @Monk: did you use the accepted answer? If so, you moved from a secure approach (your code) to a security problem (the accepted answer). Always use parameter binding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the user id to delete using the `$_POST` global array (`$_REQUEST` will work, but may put you more at risk of XSS attacks - this is because it accepts GET variables too, which can come from outside of your form).

I will figure it out where you have gone wrong.

The User ID retrieval based on the HTML that you have placed.

```
// This user id can be obtained in two ways as I suggested.
// 1.) $_REQUEST['user_id'] if you pass the data in the href link
// 2.) $_POST['user_id'] if you pass the data as hidden field in form element.
// 3.) Ensure that you get your USER ID correct  in that place by echoing the query that you have made in the SQL.
    profile.php
<a href="process.php?delete_id=<?php echo $data->id; ?>">DELETE</a>
```

process.php

```
<?php
// Ensure DB connectivity in this page. And this code will work fine.
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete_id'])){
    $id = $_REQUEST['delete_id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(":id" => $id));
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please mention why so you have made this answer is not useful. it will be helpful for me to correct it next time. Thanks :)

Comment: Sry i didn't do that. Ok so...you correct me in code. But how else? I really have no idea how to make it.

Comment: Can you please? I need example or something.

Comment: Have you made you `a` tag like this `<a href="?delete_id=<?php echo $_row_fetch['id']; ?>">DELETE</a>` If not change and ensure that your URL passes like this `useradmin.localhost/public/users?delete_id=1`

Comment: Have you completed the HTML changes @Monk.. Be a bit fast since HTML changes are easy when compared to PHP :)

Comment: Why so you are going to process.php for deleting the user. you can delete the selected user on the same page itself. as i have suggested. Your method is too long process...

Comment: You can alter the tag like this `<a href="?delete_id=<?php echo $data->id; ?>">DELETE</a>`

Comment: I have created a paste-bin as how you created. Check over there and that code will work fine bro. :) http://pastebin.com/S9h0jJwg

Comment: Ok i made something like this [link](http://pastebin.com/GguBNJZ0) and its all good. Im just having a little problem. When i hover the link i get the right id, but when i click it, my account get deleted.

Comment: Please check the changes that i have made to the code. http://pastebin.com/S9h0jJwg. Your code is wrong. You are deleting the current logged in User bro. :)

Comment: Share me if you face an hindrance still. Or share me the status of what you are getting :)

Comment: It's working now, thank you so much! Can i ask one more question? It's about `$results = $query->execute();` and `$query->close();`. Why do i need `$results` if i dont use it, and why i get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::close() in` when i put `$query->close();`? Thank you.

Comment: You can remove that $results and close action(). Since if you use separate functions alone you need to close the executed stmt. orelse you no need it.. Use only `$query->execute();`

Comment: I did, someone give you -1, now you are 0 again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122029/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-monk).

Comment: @halfer. I have changed the answer without SQL Injection. Directly executing the query once i get the request :). Hence i hope so there is no vulnerable for attack.

Comment: @halfer. I have changed the code. Please let me know whether this is correct or not..

Comment: @halfer. Thaks for rectifying my mistake and guiding me such beautifully. Happy to get advice from you ..:)

Answer (score -1):

One problem with your code is you are not actually Binding your data to your query. If you are going to use PDO, please use prepared statements.

I have created a function that deletes a row based on the `WHERE`.

```
<?php

function pdo_delete($MyConnection, $Table, $Where, $bindArray = array(), $Limit = 1) {
    $prep = $MyConnection->prepare("DELETE FROM $Table WHERE $Where LIMIT $Limit");
    foreach ($bindArray as $key => $value) {
        $prep->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }
    $prep->execute();
    $prep->closeCursor();
}

?>
```

> $MyConnection stores the pdo connection instance
>
> $Table stores the name of the table you want to target
>
> $Where stores the name of the column you want to target
>
> $bindArray Binds the data to the column and selects the rows that match
>
> $Limit is how many rows you want to allow

Here is an example on how to use this function.

- Call the function

  ```
  pdo_delete();
  ```
- Call your PDO Connection

  ```
  pdo_delete(null); // Replace null with your own pdo connection, in your case $handle
  ```
- Target a table

  ```
  pdo_delete(null, 'users');
  ```
- Where do you want to bind the data

  ```
  pdo_delete(null, 'users', 'id = :id');
  ```
- Bind the data

  ```
  pdo_delete(null, 'users', 'id = :id', array('id' => $user->id));
  ```
- Add a limit if you want... If so add another comma and type the number of rows to allow.

  ```
  pdo_delete(null, 'users', 'id = :id', array('id' => $user->id), 2); // Allows 2 columns
  ```

You can change the name of the vars/function_name/etc.

This should work, I use it for my website.

Comment: Your function is severely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: how, it uses a secure PDO Connection and it prepares each statement. I do not understand, please explain.

Comment: all the user submitted information is bind to the the prepared statement in the foreach.

Comment: I know it is SQL injection proof because i have many experiences with PDO.

Comment: In reality you cannot know beforehand which information is user-submitted and which is not. Today there is no user-submitted information and tomorrow there will be. But the fact is, almost every part of this query is not bound and therefor there can be injection in either $table, $limit, $bindArray or $where variable. You have to understand that the [extremely poor] security of this function is irrelevant to what you think of the alleged data source. Either you get a function that does protect from injection or doesn't. Despite the data source at all.

Comment: Besides, you are writing an answer on the public resource. Even if *your* data is not user-submitted, it doesn't have to be so for anyone who would pick it up here. Again, it is not the matter with the quality of the data but the matter of the quality of your function. Which *is* vulnerable to SQL injection from every direction

Comment: Yes that is true but those vars will never change, like it will always be letters because all tables are just letters. Same with where and bindArray except (`, :). I trust my input then other user because it is my website. It can be SQL Injected, but not by the connecting user.

Comment: It is a good function just needs some work on it to make it perfect.

Comment: "it is my website" - this is not true. You posted in on Stack Overflow, deliberately suggesting to use it on the other site.

Comment: Besides, "It can be SQL Injected, but not by the connecting user"  is just a delusion that was a direct reason for innumerable injections.

Comment: If you say so, i tested it and my site is secure. You think it is insecure okay, that is your opinion. I just know it users prepared statements and binds the user-submitted info to SQL query. Your opinion, lets move on.

Comment: I am just suggesting code. If you do not like it move on to the next answer. I am just trying to contribute my code.

Comment: It is not an "opinion". Nor I "don't like it". It's an explanation for the possible readers, why this function is vulnerable and thus should never be used. "Prepared statement" is not a magic chant that makes your query safe. It's a tool that can do any good if one is using it properly. You aren't.

Comment: Your clearly are not understanding my point which is kinda sad. My function is the same as typing the sql manually in the prepared statment. The user submitted information is binded like any other sql prepared statment. All the other vars are coming from your script. If you get sql injected by the other vars it is the same as sql injecting your own website. But the odds of you doing that is having low knowledge of prepared statements. I turned it into a function so it makes your script clean and easy to use. I am not using prepared statements wrong. You sir just do not understand.

Comment: Sorry, but we are talking not about you or your data here. But about this function, which is vulnerable.

Comment: No it is not if used correctly. I use it correctly so it is not vulnerable. So technically it is secure unless you don't know how to use it. You can't tell me cause i have tested it.

Comment: Cant just look at and say it is sql injection vulnerable. Actually test it out and see for your self.